# How to show all terms of a (very) large expression which was cut by skeleton << >>?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I obtained a very large expression but I noticed that Mathematica omitted some terms and wrote <<1>> or <<8>> instead. I would like to see all terms in order to write rules that simplify calculations.

Comment: Which version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Comment: Mathematica 9 Student version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In recent versions of *Mathematica* you should see something like this:

```
RandomInteger[99, {500, 50}]
```

[image]

Or like this (version 7):

[image]

Clicking **show all** or **Show Full Output** should do just that.  Be aware that if the expression is large this can hang the Front End or consume all your RAM.

Within the preferences you should also have something like this (the last line shown):

[image]

If you are getting [`Skeleton`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Skeleton.html) output that is unaffected by the setting above and without the dialogs shown I believe it must be generated by an explicit use of [`Short`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Short.html) or [`Shallow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Shallow.html) somewhere, perhaps internally, and you will need to include an example of the code that is producing it.